# Whats the easiest way to change several values at predetermined locations in a 2D vector?

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, points, 2d-vector

Ok so I have a 2d vector of chars that I call a grid. Lets just say its 70 x 30. When the grid is created, it automatically fills each position with 'x'

I have a function that displays the grid. So I call this function and a 70x30 grid of x's is displayed to the console.

I have another function that I want to call to essentially replace the char at certain x,y coordinates of the grid with a different char. The points aren't exactly random/scattered. I'm basically starting from a point on the edge of the grid, and drawing zigzagged lines to another edge. All points are predetermined. Theres a lot of points to plot, so manually doing it seems inefficient.

Here's how I was thinking to do it:

- Create a double for loop, width and height, calling them i and j
- If i = (a || b || c || d...) && j = (e || f || g..)

And essentially do that tedious process for each possible scenario..
Surely there is a much easier and simpler way lol. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You could always use a single dimensional array and index it two dimensionally.

Comment: It seems like you have a list of coordinates on the grid to replace. Why don't you just go through that list and index only the cells you need to replace?

Answer (score 0):

If the points can be pre-determined by having a map (as in for a level editor or otherwised fixed pattern), then make a dictionary of x/y co-ordinates to what the tile becomes. Iterate over the dictionary and do each replacement.

If the points aren't pre-determined but follow a pattern, such as lines or blobs, then write a method that draws the line/blob/whatever and call it over and over. The method decides which tiles to replace and replaces those.

Btw, there's a trick when doing 2D checking and processing like this which is called having a 'delta', for instance xdelta=-1, ydelta=0 is west and xdelta=1, ydelta=1 is northeast. By having a delta you can run a function two, four or eight times with different deltas and it'll move in different directions by just using the delta's directions instead of needing to try all eight directions on its own - the delta can also be used to drive the bounds checking if you want, as you can't go out of bounds in a direction you're not proceeding in for example. Then you can go further and have an enumeration of all directions, functions that invert a direction, that turn a direction 90/45 degrees (if it's enumerated it's very simple, you just add 2 or 1 to the enumeration and return the new direction), etc, making processing very easy now.

So I might have something like

`function drawLine(int xstart, int ystart, int xdelta, intydelta)`

that starts at xstart,ystart, replaces the tile with O, adds xdelta to x, adds ydelta to y, replaces the tile with O, etc until it falls off the edge.